# see the dll comments in c#

Tags: c#, comments

I have written the c# comments of my function,and then i gave the dll file to my friends who need it,but when he use those functions ,he can't see the comments,how to solve this problem?

Ps: I can see the comments when i use it in my project;

Comment: Check out GhostDoc or Atomineer for comment generation. There not perfect but they can get you started.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Comments are ripped off the assembly, you'll have to [generate the xml documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0.aspx) for your project and give it to your friend. If both files (assembly and xml documentation) are in the same directory Visual Studio will use the documentation in IntelliSense.

(*Xml documentation [can't be embedded in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200920/embedding-intellisense-xml-documentation-in-assembly)*)

Answer (score 15):

You need to build the XML documentation file for the project as well (tick the box in the Build part of the project properties) and give your friends that file as well as the DLL.

If they put the two files in the same directory, Visual Studio will pick up the documentation automatically and show it in IntelliSense etc.

Note that this will *only* pick up XML comments (the ones started with `///` or `/**`), not regular comments.