# How can I get ServiceStack's XML documentation to show in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, servicestack, nuget, xml-documentation

I am trying out ServiceStack, through OrmLite obtained via NuGet, but the XML documentation does not show up in the IDE when hovering on elements.

When I look at the [source in Github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/65adc464852240193a6352046187b9de156e5ccf/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs), it seems to be properly documented, but since there is no xml file in the NuGet source folder, I guess this is the reason as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863664/see-the-dll-comments-in-c-sharp).

Why is the xml file not included in the NuGet distribution, and where can I find it (without recompiling ServiceStack myself)?